# Zod coercion to date custom error message

Tags: typescript, date, datetime, validation, zod

I have a zod schema that needs to validate a datetime from html input.
Here's how it looks:

```
const appointmentSchema = z.object({
  appointmentTime: z.coerce.date()
})
```

The problem is when I interact with the input and it is invalid, like the image below. Zod returns me the following error message: `Invalid date`.

[image]

I want to customize this message but nothing seems to work, I've already tried the following:

```
...z.coerce.date({
invalid_type_error: 'Custom invalid date message. Doesn't work...'
})...
```

Comment: Its a bug in zod. See here for explanation and workaround: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1526

Comment: which zod version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Zod ^3.22.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @adsy in the comments. This is a known issue https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1526

The workaround is overriding the errorMap:

```
dateOfBirth: z
        .date({
          errorMap: (issue, { defaultError }) => ({
            message: issue.code === "invalid_date" ? "That's not a date!" : defaultError,
          }),
        })
```